Xlwings Converting a Cell to an Excel DataType (e.g., Stocks, Currencies)
I'm trying to setup a command using Xlwings within a Python script to set a specific cell within an Excel worksheet to an Excel Data type (e.g., Stocks, Currencies). I've found the VBA code that sets to these "newer" Excel Data types that return values from Microsoft's online services. However I'm not having any luck in getting this code to work.
Any feedback would be appreciated.
Using:
MacOS: Sequoia v15.1
Excel: Excel for Mac 2021
Sample code:
wb = xw.Book(file)
sheet = wb.sheets('Stock_DataTable')

sheet.Range("B19").api.ConvertToLinkedDataType ServiceID:=268435456, LanguageCulture:= "en-US"


Expected result: format the cell as the specified data type and return the correct information from the web-service


Observed result: the call simply fails with a message saying that this is not a supported function.


What you have would only give a syntax error. The line would have to be something like:- sheet.range("B19").api.ConvertToLinkedDataType(ServiceID=268435456, LanguageCulture="en-US")

moken - Thanks for the response I'd upvote but I don't have enough posts yet. Yes Microsoft's reference page for VBA had the odd spacing. I tried it as you suggested and got the following error:
AttributeError: Unknown property, element or command: 'ConvertToLinkedDataType'
My assumption is that Mac doesn't support accessing this API. I'd welcome any other suggestions.

Have you tried accessing the data manually or using the command given in VBA to see if you can use the service? I don't have a 365 account at the moment so I cannot use the service and cannot test any further.

Good suggestion I just tried it and this VBA code in MacOS Excel 2021 works perfectly.
Sub ConvertToLinkedDataTypeTest()
' Ensure the range contains text compatible with the linked data type
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("B4") ' Adjust as necessary
On Error Resume Next
rng.ConvertToLinkedDataType ServiceID:=268435456, LanguageCulture:="en-US"
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
Else
    MsgBox "Linked Data Type conversion successful!", vbInformation
End If

End Sub
